# Form Collection in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to create by code a collection/list of forms like this:

`Public fs() As Form = {Form1, Form2}`

But it doesn't work because forms are classes and cannot be used as expressions. How do I do? Thanks.

Comment: If you want a form collection you'd want to store save the instance variable.  But it is also a bit odd to create a form instance before you need it to interact with the user, so it is not clear what you are tring to do.

Answer (score 2):

Well, presumably `Form1` and `Form2` are types of your project and no instantiated form variables. So if the expression `{ Form1, Form2}` is intended to return an array of `Type`, then use a Type-Array:

```
Public fs() As Type = { GetType(Form1), GetType(Form2) }
```

But if you have variables instantiated like this somewhere else:

```
Dim Form1 As Form1 = New Form1()
Dim Form2 As Form2 = New Form2()
```

Then your expression should work. However please note that naming variables like their types is not a good idea. Especially not in Visual Basic.

If you have no variables but you want to have an array holding two form instances, then go like this:

```
Public fs() As Form = { New Form1(), New Form2() }
```

Comment: If it gives me this error obviously the forms aren't instantiated like that.

Comment: Wow, well ... WHAT error? You did not say anything about it.

Comment: That classes can't be used as expressions.

Comment: And what do you want to achieve? "A collection of forms" is not that clear. Instances? If yes, existing ones or new ones? Of no, then their types?

Comment: Instances of existing ones.

Comment: Well, there's everything you need right in front of you. I don't want to push anymore now. Not in a tight-lipped conversation like this one.